# Getting name of windows computer running python script?

Tags: python, windows, networking

I have a couple Windows computers on my network that will be running a python script.  A different set of configuration options should be used in the script depending on which computer is running this script.

How would I get that computer name in the python script?

Let's say the script was running on a computer named DARK-TOWER, I'd like to write something like this:

```
>>> python.library.get_computer_name()
'DARK-TOWER'
```

Is there a standard or third party library I can use?

Answer (score 221, accepted):

It turns out there are three options (including the two already answered earlier):

```
>>> import platform
>>> import socket
>>> import os
>>> platform.node()
'DARK-TOWER'
>>> socket.gethostname()
'DARK-TOWER'
>>> os.environ['COMPUTERNAME'] # WORK ONLY ON WINDOWS
'DARK-TOWER'
```

Comment: Answering one's own question may be considered poor taste by some, but it is perfectly fine, as per the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I don't think it's bad at all, since Eric was compiling a few different responses into a single resource, not to mention adding a new one (platform).

Comment: ok, so this cries out for a follow-up: what's the difference between platform.node() and socket.gethostname() ? can they ever be different?

Comment: On posix systems, `socket.gethostname()` returns the libc `gethostname()`, while `platform.node()` returns `platform.uname()[1]` which is somewhat related to `os.uname()` which calls the libc `uname()`... It looks like they might end up in the same place, but they take quite different paths to get there and I wouldn't be relying on the value to be the same across different platforms.

Comment: On one side it wasn't one second answer, on the other side you got 3 to 4 perfectly acceptable answers before you did yours.

Comment: Worth noting that `os.environ['COMPUTERNAME']` will return all uppercase, whereas `platform.node()` and `socket.gethostname()` can return mixed case.

Comment: `os.environ['COMPUTERNAME']` returns an error for me: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/billtubbs/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'COMPUTERNAME'`

Comment: os.environ['COMPUTERNAME'] not always working, This environment variable is not set on my computer running Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: ```File "/usr/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None```

on linux when COMPUTERNAME is used

Answer (score 49):

```
import socket
socket.gethostname()
```

Comment: +1 for this being the best way to go. It's the most effective cross-platform call.

Comment: `platform.node()`
is crossplatform too

Comment: Computer name and host name are two different things. For example, when you are in a VPN, your host name is X and your computer name can be Y. This answer is not correct, since the question is about COMPUTER name and not host name.

Comment: this works for me, while using `os` doesn't

Answer (score 23):

From https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2006-April/397494.html

```
import os
os.getenv('COMPUTERNAME')
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me on OS-X 10.6.8 using Python 2.7.2, it returns None. The other methods described do work however.

Comment: @PeterGibson I had the same thing occurring to me on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Returns `None` for me on Ubuntu 16.04. Interestingly, `HOSTNAME` is a defined environment variable in bash, but both `os.getenv('HOSTNAME')` returns `None` also, while `socket.gethostname()` returns the correct string.

Answer (score 18):

As Eric Palakovich Carr said you could use these three variants.

I prefer using them together:

```
def getpcname():
    n1 = platform.node()
    n2 = socket.gethostname()
    n3 = os.environ["COMPUTERNAME"]
    if n1 == n2 or n1 == n3:
        return n1
    elif n2 == n3:
        return n2
    else:
        raise Exception("Computernames are not equal to each other")
```

I prefer it when developing cross patform applications to be sure ;)

Comment: Just a bit cleaner:

    if n1==n2 or n2==n3:
       return n1
    elif n2==n3:
       return n2
    else:
       raise Exception("Computer names are not equal to each other")

Comment: @CharlesPlager It should be: `if n1==n2 or n1==n3: return n1 elif n2==n3: return n2 else: raise Exception("Computer names are not equal to each other")` (`n1` instead of `n2`)

Comment: @dexteritas: You are correct.  (It won't let me edit it for whatever reason).

Comment: You could use os.getenv("COMPUTERNAME") which returns None instead of raising error if "COMPUTERNAME" does not exist in env.

Answer (score 8):

Since the python scrips are for sure running on a windows system, you should use the Win32 API [GetComputerName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724295(VS.85).aspx) or [GetComputerNameEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724301(VS.85).aspx)

You can get the fully qualified DNS name, or NETBIOS name, or a variety of different things.

```
import win32api
win32api.GetComputerName()

>>'MYNAME'
```

Or:

```
import win32api
WIN32_ComputerNameDnsHostname = 1 
win32api.GetComputerNameEx(WIN32_ComputerNameDnsHostname)

>> u'MYNAME'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import socket
pc = socket.gethostname()
print pc
```

Comment: Please add always some explanation to the answer.

Comment: Besides, this answer is just a copy of a 10-year old highly-upvoted other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/799783/10669875).

Answer (score 3):

I bet [gethostname](http://pydoc.org/1.6/socket.html#-gethostname) will work beautifully.