# Python get device-name

Tags: python, device-name

im not new in Python but I have one question left: How do I get the name of the Computer that im on/Device ? I tried many things, this is the last thing, I was in the os Module and found something but if i start the script, it gives me an error that in the os module isn't a 'getDeviceName' function.

```
from os import *

os.getDeviceName()
```

Comment: check this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799767/getting-name-of-windows-computer-running-python-script

Answer (score 9):

```
import socket
socket.gethostname()
```

would also work just fine.

Answer (score 5):

to get the machine name, see `platform.node()`:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.node

example:

```
import platform
print(platform.node())
```

Comment: If performance is of any consideration, this should be the top answer!:
```% python -m timeit "import platform;platform.node()"
1000000 loops, best of 5: 238 nsec per loop
```

vs.

```% python -m timeit "import socket;socket.gethostname()"
50000 loops, best of 5: 6.93 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

## CMD:

```
echo %USERNAME% > ["drive"]:\["path"]\["filename"].["extension"]
```

## example:

```
echo %USERNAME% > C:\username.uf
```

## python:

```py
path = open("C:\\username.uf", 'r')

username = path.readlines()

print(username)
```

## Console:

```
['"your username will display here" /n']
```

*if u don't want this '/n' then u can replace it...
i know this will take some extra time but for me this is good cuz ima begginer but i learned some other things to print it just by using python*