# How to get path to folder on system running python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to save some files generated by my program to `"<drive_name>\Users\<computer_name>\Documents"` folder.

I need the drive and computer name. What would be a neat way to achieve this. I usually get the current working directory and just split the string to get that info but there has to be a better way right?

Comment: You could make use of environment variables to get the path to the `User` folder and the computer name. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/how-do-i-access-environment-variables-in-python and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-recognized-environment-variables

Comment: e.g. `os.environ['COMPUTERNAME']`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799767/getting-name-of-windows-computer-running-python-script

Answer (score 0):

`pathlib` is more pythonic.

ex)

```py
In [1]: from pathlib import Path

In [2]: path = Path('~').resolve()

In [3]: path
Out[3]: PosixPath('/home/phi/git/python/etl/~')
```

just declare `path = Path(__file__)` in your script.